# How do I create a Github Action that will convert my markdown files into a single .json file

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to create a Github Action that will take multiple markdown files and convert them into a single .json file. I tried the following and it did not work.

I used this found script.

```
// filename: buildJson.js

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const matter = require("gray-matter");

const getAll = dir => {
  // Read files at _posts/{directory}
  const directory = path.join(process.cwd(), `content/${dir}`);
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(directory);
  // Get the content of the files as JSON
  const content = fileNames.map((fileName, index) => {
    const slug = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, "");
    const fullPath = path.join(directory, fileName);
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, "utf8");
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents);
    return {
      id: index + 1, slug, ...matterResult
    };
  });
  // Return a big array of JSON
  return JSON.stringify(content);
};

const allPosts = getAll("blog");

const postFileContents = `${allPosts}`;

// Create the cache folder if it doesn't exist
try {
  fs.readdirSync("public/cache");
} catch (e) {
  fs.mkdirSync("public/cache");
}

// Create our cached posts JSON
fs.writeFile("public/cache/posts.json", postFileContents, err => {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log("Posts cached.");
});
```

and this yml file in .github/workflows

```
name: create-json
on: [push]
jobs:
  create-json:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - run: npm install 
      - run: node buildJson.js
```

The script ran in Github Actions, it outputted the conole.log message I left myself, it did not create the .json file.